# [AMI]How do I execute one Node.js process?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ami

Off course, 
I know Node.js is a single  threaded language.
But something is wrong...

Environment:

OS:

```
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2018.03"
```

Node.js:

```
$ node -v
v8.12.0
```

(installed with nodebrew)

I executed this.

hoge.js:

```
$ cat  hoge.js
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  console.log('hoge');
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
$ node hoge.js
hoge
hoge
hoge
hoge
hoge
.
.
```

htop(an interactive process viewer like top command):

```
PID   USER     PRI NI VIRT RES   SHR  S  CPU%  MEM%  TIME+ Command
10001 ec2-user 20  0  971M 149M 22188 R  54.0  7.5 0:05.79 node hoge.js
10002 ec2-user 20  0  971M 149M 22188 S  0.0   7.5 0:00.03 node hoge.js
10003 ec2-user 20  0  971M 149M 22188 S  0.0   7.5 0:00.07 node hoge.js
10004 ec2-user 20  0  971M 149M 22188 S  0.0   7.5 0:00.07 node hoge.js
10005 ec2-user 20  0  971M 149M 22188 S  0.0   7.5 0:00.07 node hoge.js
```

What's happening?

I want to execute this with ONE process.
Is there any config file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Those are probably many threads of a single process.

By default, `htop` also shows threads, not processes. You can change this behavior in its settings ("Show userland threads" / "Color userland threads").

While Node is single-threaded as far as running user code is concerned, it still has internal threads to do e.g. garbage collection or other things.

Comment: Essentially, only the event loop is single threaded. It still has various threads, for example, the libuv thread pool